# Strange HDD behavior on windows

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, lenovo-laptop

Recently i started having a strange issue with windows 10 where my disk usage stays 100% at 0.1 MB/s usage and it's not coming down unti a few hours

**Here's a list of things i've tried:**

- i thought maybe updating would help but it made it worse and the device never came down of 100% usage as long as i was watching it (about ~3hrs)
- i thought maybe it's a windows bugs or maybe some malware that i'm not aware of so i backed up my inportant codes and stuff using a ubuntu live flash then wiped the whole thing, then created 3 partitions which i used for a Ubuntu Desktop, the latest version of windows and a big partition called Storage for data storing
- i'm still writing this on that Ubuntu Desktop that i'm pretty okay with, but the windows part went nuclear as soon as i finished updating it and didn't even boot anymore
- i also tried a version of windows called LTSC which is an old version of windows but the same results,
- i also benchmarked my drives and they where beyond fine
- and made a single partition beside the ubuntu one with the whole hdd storage and ran badblocks on it that took several hours to complete and found 0 badblocks

i'm actually out of ideas is there any other thing that i can test to fix this issue?

**i'm using Lenovo Legion y520 15IKBN if that helps**

Thanks for your attention

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs, punctuation, and bullet points ... and correct spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, here's what i did which seems to have fixed it:

- Reinstalled windows (in the installation do not allocate any other drives but the windows one)
- After the new installation, used Snappy Driver Pack to update my drivers instead of typical windows update
- When it finished updating, installed NVIDIA Drivers from it's site
- Allocated my drive through windows disk managements
- Ran boot-repair on a live ubuntu to fix my dual boot settings
- Disabled windows update ( actually just paused it through setting no services or registery)

After this things look to be working fine with no issue

Comment: **Do not disable Windows Update.** It leaves your computer without updates that are necessary for its security.